# New CRA typescript errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

On a fresh CRA with typescript flag, I open up any of the default tsx files and get errors.

- Cannot find module `react.ts(2307)`
- Cannot use JSX unless the `--jsx` flag is `provided.ts(17004)`

I've made multiple tsconfig changes to try and remove these errors but nothing seems to help. One being "JSX": "react".

Below are the default packages pulled in which include the types.

```
 @types/jest@24.0.15
 react-dom@16.8.6
 react@16.8.6
 @types/react@16.8.23
 react-scripts@3.0.1
 @types/react-dom@16.8.5
 @types/node@12.6.8
 typescript@3.5.3
```

Below is a link showing the default CRA generated App.tsx.

[image: Error Image]

**** UPDATE ****

I found that this only happens when I spin up a project on my DO server and code from there but not when I do it locally on my mac. Is there a way to get rid of the errors and be able to code on a server instead of locally?

Comment: what version of CRA do you have installed globally?

Comment: @JohnRuddell 3.0.1

Comment: and what command did you use to create the app? I just did `yarn create react-app my-app --typescript` from the [**docs here**](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript). no issues

Comment: @JohnRuddell npx create-react-app client --typescript

Comment: Is this error when running the app or only in VSCode? If it's in VSCode try "reload project", or alternatively "reload window".

Comment: That works for me as well with the same CRA version lol. Maybe restart vs-code (assuming you're using that IDE). Install updates... etc.

Comment: I just tried yarn and got the same issue. I'm using VSCode and so far I think I'm at 20+ times on reloading the window and a few times of a full IDE restart during the times I was trying every suggestion from my google searching earlier with no luck lol. I am on a windows PC atm at work but I saw the same issues on my mac last night. I guess I should have mentioned about when the errors pop up. It's while coding which if I turn the validate option off in VSCode for typescript they go away. So the app will run and I can navigate to it on the browser fine. I just have a wall of red while coding.

Comment: I added an image to the post so y'all can see what I'm talking about,